# MySql - Innodb - Corrupt Index / Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb

I have a friggin bizarre situation going on. One of my nightly queries, which usually takes 5 mins, took >12 hours. Here is the query:

```
SELECT  Z.id,
        Z.seoAlias,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT LOWER(A.include)) AS include,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT LOWER(A.exclude)) AS exclude
FROM df_productsbystore         AS X
INNER JOIN df_product_variants  AS Y ON Y.id = X.id_variant
INNER JOIN df_products          AS Z ON Z.id = Y.id_product
INNER JOIN df_advertisers       AS A ON A.id = X.id_store
WHERE X.isActive > 0
AND Z.id > 60301433
GROUP BY Z.id
ORDER BY Z.id
LIMIT 45000;
```

I ran an EXPLAIN and got the following:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+---------+---------------------+------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                                                                      | key       | key_len | ref                 | rows | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+---------+---------------------+------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | A     | ALL    | PRIMARY                                                                            | NULL      | NULL    | NULL                |  365 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | X     | ref    | UNIQUE_variantAndStore,idx_isActive,idx_store                                      | idx_store | 4       | foenix.A.id         |  600 | Using where                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Y     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,UNIQUE,idx_prod                                                            | PRIMARY   | 4       | foenix.X.id_variant |    1 | Using where                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Z     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,UNIQUE_prods_seoAlias,idx_brand,idx_gender2,fk_df_products_id_category_idx | PRIMARY   | 4       | foenix.Y.id_product |    1 | NULL                            |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+---------+---------------------+------+---------------------------------+
```

Which looked different to my development environment. The df_advertisers section looked fishy to me, so I deleted and recreated the index on the X.id_store column, and now the EXPLAIN looks like this and the query is fast again:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+---------+-------------------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                                                                      | key                    | key_len | ref               | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+---------+-------------------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Z     | range  | PRIMARY,UNIQUE_prods_seoAlias,idx_brand,idx_gender2,fk_df_products_id_category_idx | PRIMARY                | 4       | NULL              | 2090691 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Y     | ref    | PRIMARY,UNIQUE,idx_prod                                                            | UNIQUE                 | 4       | foenix.Z.id       |       1 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | X     | ref    | UNIQUE_variantAndStore,idx_isActive,idx_id_store                                   | UNIQUE_variantAndStore | 4       | foenix.Y.id       |       1 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | A     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                            | PRIMARY                | 4       | foenix.X.id_store |       1 | NULL        |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+---------+-------------------+---------+-------------+
```

It would appear that the index magically disappeared. Can anyone explain how this is possible? Am I mean to run a `mysqlcheck` command or similar on a regular basis to avoid this kind of thing? I'm stumped!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next time, simply do `ANALYZE TABLE df_productsbystore;`  It will be very fast, and *may* solve the problem.

`ANALYZE` recomputes the statistics on which the Optimizer depends for deciding, in this case, which table to start with.  In rare situations, the stats get out of date and need a kick in the shin.

Caveat:  I am assuming you are using InnoDB on a somewhat recent version.  If you are using MyISAM, then `ANALYZE` is needed more often.

Do you really need 45K rows?  What will you do with so many?

A way to speed the query up (probably) is to do everything you can with X and Z in a subquery, *then* `JOIN A` to do the rest:

```
SELECT  XYZ.id, XYZ.seoAlias,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT LOWER(A.include)) AS include,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT LOWER(A.exclude)) AS exclude
    FROM  
    (
        SELECT  Z.id, Z.seoAlias, X.id_store
            FROM  df_productsbystore AS X
            INNER JOIN  df_product_variants AS Y  ON Y.id = X.id_variant
            INNER JOIN  df_products AS Z          ON Z.id = Y.id_product
            WHERE  X.isActive > 0
              AND  Z.id > 60301433
            GROUP BY  Z.id -- may not be necessary ??
            ORDER BY  Z.id
            LIMIT  45000 
    ) AS XYZ
    INNER JOIN  df_advertisers AS A  ON A.id = XYZ.id_store
    GROUP BY  ZYZ.id
    ORDER BY  XYZ.id;
```

Useful indexes:

```
Y: INDEX(id_product, id)
X: INDEX(id_variant, isActive, id_store)
```

Comment: Hi Rick, thanks for the post. ANALYZE did not seem to work, I think our DB was messed up :(

Comment: Did the reformulated query, plus indexes make not difference, either?

Comment: Hi Rick, your reformulated query is excellent. When the machine was running quickly the difference was marginal. But subsequently the machine ran slower, and your query was significantly faster. All I can think is that it was related to caching. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix the problem I tried removing and recreating the index + FK. This did not solve the problem the first time, while the machine was under load, but it did work the second time, on a quiet machine.

It just feels like mysql is flaky. I really don't know what else to say.

Thanks for the help though